# SQL Select In Select for insert Stement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm wondering whats wrong with that Statement.

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Myname,category ) 
 SELECT TOP 1 thenames
FROM tNames
 WHERE DateAdded > DATEADD(Day, -10, GETDATE() 
ORDER BY NEWID(),@ccategory)
```

I want to pick one random value from table tnames and put it in table 1 with category values that i got from SP.
How should I do that?

**EDITS:**
I'm working in MS SQL Server.
Complete code:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Names_SP] 
@CCategory nvarchar(50)

AS

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Table1(Myname,category ) 
     SELECT TOP 1 thenames
    FROM tNames
     WHERE DateAdded > DATEADD(Day, -10, GETDATE() 
    ORDER BY NEWID(),@ccategory)
END
```

When I call SP I send @ccategory. Since table 1 has 2 columns (the first is category) I want to get the second (myname) column value from tname table as random (names that have been added in 10 days).

Comment: MySQL or Sql-Server? That are two different things.

Comment: Which dbms `sql server` or `mysql` ?

Comment: Thanks for mentioning it. I've just edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 Columns you want to insert in (Myname, category)
but your select list only contains 1 column! (thenames)

What about "@category"? At least in your posted code this variable is never declared or assigned...

Maybe you should do something like this:

```
DECLARE  @category varchar(20)
SET @category = 'some cat.'    

INSERT INTO Table1(Myname,category)
    SELECT TOP 1 thenames,@category
    FROM tNames
    WHERE DateAdded > DATEADD(Day, -10, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are selecting One Column from Select statement and There are Two Columns specified in insert statement

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Myname) 
 SELECT TOP 1 thenames
FROM tNames
 WHERE DateAdded > DATEADD(Day, -10, GETDATE() 
ORDER BY NEWID(),@ccategory)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select the exact values which are written in insert statement. Somthing like this:-

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Myname,category ) 
SELECT TOP 1 thenames, Category_value
FROM tNames
WHERE DateAdded > DATEADD(Day, -10, GETDATE())
ORDER BY NEWID(),@ccategory
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO Table1(Myname,category ) 
 SELECT TOP 1 thenames,@ccategory
FROM tNames
 WHERE DateAdded > DATEADD(Day, -10, GETDATE() ORDER BY NEWID(),@ccategory)
```

You should pass same parameters combinataion of insert and select statement